# How to start a session?

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want my earth.php file to find the users id when a user enter mysite.com/earth.php. I want this because I want the id to be placed in a sql code that will be sent to the database when the user enters mysite.com/earth.php. And I think I have to start a session when a user logs in to help the earth.php to find the user id? Can someone help me with that because I don't know how to do it.

This is my earth.php file:

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

    session_start();
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
session_write_close();

    $verbindung = mysql_connect("localhost","root","******");
    mysql_select_db("lan");

if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
  mysql_query("UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id='$id'");  
}

     ?>
```

And this is the value I want to be changed for the user to 3 when they enters mysite.com/earth.php
[image: http://prntscr.com/4turly]

This is my login.php file 
[image: http://prntscr.com/4tm6jz]

Please help, I've been trying to solve this problem for a long time.

Comment: Have you actually set `$_SESSION['id']` to have a value?

Comment: You have started your session without actually populating it

Comment: How do I set a value then? and what does the value do?

Comment: I was just about to ask that.....where is $_SESSION['id'] actually set?

Comment: `$id` in your login.php file has no value. Therefore `$_SESSION['id']` is null. Resulting in you effectively querying `"UPDATE users SET ally='3' WHERE id=NULL`

Comment: $_SESSION['id'] = $something

Comment: I don't know? how do I set it? This Is the files I use session in?

Comment: @AdRock is spot on with what you need to do. Your session isn't holding any information as it's not setting it anywhere. Give it a value, and you'll be fine

Comment: Where should I place this code then?  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

Comment: Where are your userIds generated. And do they use these userIds in mysite.com before they navigate to earth.php.

Comment: Yes they login Sai Phani

Comment: How about moving `session_write_close();` to the end of the file, or using `isset($id)` instead of `isset($_SESSION['id'])`?

Comment: When they login, You might have the login details to login.php. right?
There use session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=$_POST['userid'];// this userid is name of input field in login form

Comment: Wait, do you want me to use this code somewhere? session_start(); $_SESSION['id']=$_POST['userid'];//

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
<?php

define('DB_TYPE', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_NAME', 'dbname');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', 'password');

session_start();

try {
    // create a new instance of a PDO connection
    $db = new PDO(DB_TYPE.':host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    // if the connection fails, display an error message
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $sql = 'SELECT userid, username FROM users WHERE username = :username';

    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue('username', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

    $_SESSION['id'] = $result[0]['userid'];

    var_dump($_SESSION['id']);  //this will show the the session
}

?>
```

Comment: That is an example of a login.  The form action would go here, get the id of the user and then set the session. I would update that so it checks if the username exists and if it does, then set the session otherwise give a message to the user

Comment: So, can I replace this code with my login.php that I use right now?

Comment: It's up to you but i don't know what your login.php looks like.  That's where you want to set the session. Also have a look at learning PDO or MySQLi (I prefer PDO)

Comment: My login file looks like this http://prntscr.com/4tuxgf

Comment: From what I can see, i don't see any login. Have you got a database with users in there?

Comment: Wait, do you want to see my database?

Comment: Cause in my database I have a "logins" that looks like this http://prntscr.com/4tuyff

Comment: Just update your database details with yours and change id in sql query and $result to your id field in database

Comment: Can you explain a little more, I don't understand. Sorry I haven't been doing this for a long time

Comment: You need a login form with a username field with a name of username.  The database details need to be updated with your database name, database, username and password etc.  The sql query needs to be updated with your database table so when your login form should direct to this code and it will output the session

Comment: Im lost, is it any code I should add? and if it is, where should I add it?

Comment: Replace your current login.php with the code i pasted. Just make sure your database details are changed to your details and make sure the database table is changed also

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your code, the `$_SESSION['id']` is empty. Set a value for it. I see you edited your post. Then you just have to include your file after starting the session like

`session_start();
 include_once 'path/to/login/php/login.php;`

Comment: While this is correct, please explain a bit better with a snippet of code explaining the issue

Comment: Where should I place this code then?  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

Comment: $id needs to have a value @EmrikAhlström in order to set the session.

Comment: How to do I give it a value?

Comment: When the user logs in using your login.php, you set the session there.   I presume you query database with username or something and return an id.  Set that id in the session

Comment: Adrock, how do I do that? can you give me a code?

Comment: Krisztian, this is what happens when I add your code http://prntscr.com/4tuvce

Comment: **I think OP is trolling.**

Comment: One does not simply session_write_closes a session twice...

Comment: In your login.php you have session_write_close(). Then you have session_write_close() again in your earth.php. I don't even know what do you want to achieve. You should accept @AdRock's answer. Anyway the session_write_close writes the session and ends it. You may want to remove session_write_close from the login.php and insert it into the earth.php. I don't understand why you want to use session_write_close, the session will be ended when closing browser or you can `unset($_SESSION['id'])` and your session will live but the id element wont persist.